# Zabbix trigger as INACTIVE

Tags: zabbix, perfmon

I'm trying to make an Item/trigger where:

When the counter reachs 0 , then send me emails.

I'm using perfmon for this.

The counter i'm using is :

`PERF_COUNTER["\\HQPC30599\MSSQL$DBA_SQL:General Statistics\User Connections"]`

This is the expression i'm using:

```
{MAQUINA DBA TESTE:PERF_COUNTER["\\HQPC30599\MSSQL$DBA_SQL:General Statistics\User Connections"].last()}=0
```

but when I check the trigger, it says INACTIVE:

[image]

With the error message `unsuported Item Key`.

Why is this happening? has anyone passed for this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the triggers until your items work. In this case, the item does not work.
The error tells you that the item key is wrong. You used `PERF_COUNTER` as the key, but [the correct key](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent/win_keys) is `perf_counter` - you uppercased it for some unknown reason.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. But I have another counter with perf_counter in lower case, but stills doesnt work

Comment: That sounds like a different question - please post it separately so that it is possible to keep track.